# How to use unlimited list of arguments to a command in bash shell?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm running up against the "argument list too long" problem using a command in the shell (bash in my case). Most suggestions for working around this suggest using `find` or some variation, presuming that it's a long list of files that is exceeding the argument length limit.

However, in my case it's not a list of files but a list of arguments. I'm using the audio processing software `sox` and need to be able to use as many command line arguments as I want (depending on input audio file length). So, for example, a short version of a command I want might look like:

`sox input.wav output.wav trim 0 1 gain 1 : trim 0 1 gain 2 : trim 0 1 gain 1`

But instead of just three trim/gain arg pairs, I want it to go on for as long as I want (so imagine that it just keeps going with `trim 0 1 gain X`.

Is there any way to write a function to generate this in order to subvert the arg length limit? I tried some variations but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Look into `xargs(1)`.

Comment: Wouldn't xargs invoke the main command many times? I want to be able to only execute the main command once with an unlimited number of arguments.

Comment: In that case, did you try `sox`’s `--effects-file` option?

Comment: Wow, thank you for the pointer. There was no mention of this option in any of the documentation that came with sox, though after your comment I found one mention in the ChangeLog, and then found info on the mailing list. This does solve my problem.

Comment: @spiff You might want to make an answer from your comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

If a solution specific to `sox` would meet your immediate needs, I see from the `sox(1)` man page that it has an option `--effects-file` that lets you specify all your edits in a file instead of command line arguments.